# Are using views in sql no longer necessary?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I just got floored by a command from my manager, saying that in our newest version of our coldfusion 8 powered site, we would not be using any views.

He believes that what our contractor said with Coldfusion 8, that the performance benefit is minimal, and that it is very inconvenient to have to lookup the code for a view.

We do have a development server, with coldfusion, iis, and sql server 2005 on it, but the other programmer and my manager either refuse to use it or don't care. I don't think they really understand the importance of a dev server and source control but that's not my main question.

We do have a lot of custom reports, and having worked only a year here, and only part-time, it has been very hard to get a handle on their database, so using views for reporting in our new version would make it much easier to grab certain sets of data, rather than have all the complex joins in the coldfusion code.

I will respect his wishes, of course, I am just totally floored by the lack of evidence backing up this decision.

On our production server we have Coldfusion 8 Standard, IIS7, SQL Server 2008.

I can understand the ease of seeing all the sql, but I use ssms every day, looking at tables, views and stored procedures, so I don't claim to be an expert, but I am reasonably familiar with sql server.

And I guess that's what I really expect from them, to have some solid reasons for not using views.

Am I being irrational?

I don't want to get into arguments, that's pointless, but it's so hard when they don't even have a solid development life cycle, or use source control.

I don't want to be the anal sob, being rude or making them feel uncomfortable, but I just dont' get it why they aren't adopting to what I consider basic must have, in any kind of solid web programming company or department.

Sorry for long post, just this bothers me, I want to make sure this decision makes sense for performance reasons, or maybe I just have too few clout to ever make them see why this decision is wrong, and i will have to accept it.

But is there any clear provable evidence, that we don't need to use views with coldfusion/sql server anymore?

Comment: This is a year old now.  I was wondering if you have a post mortem report.  Did you persuade your team to continue with views? If so, how? If not, how did the project turn out?

Comment: I no longer work for that company, and wish them the best. However, their desire to pursue no learning, no education, and to just assume that any contractor/consultant always had the best ideas or solutions, regardless of whether their own internal people disagreed, seems a very odd behavior pattern. Why is that manager's trust their own people so little, and anyone else is 1000% trusted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the short of it is **NO**.

Views arent dead, they havent even staggered yet, instead I think it has a lot more uses than most think.

In a situation like this, I would rather have an informative discussion with the others. Preprare yourself, get some documentation, and put together a little presentation. Show the pros and cons of your ways, and be open to discussion. But always remember, as the Client is always right, so the Manager/Boss thinks they are...

Comment: I agree, but I think honestly I need some solid proof to even open the discussion up. I don't want to cause problems, but I don't want us to create a new site with invalid premises. Where can i get some proof?

Comment: Not to sound obvious, but start with the MS site. They have many articles explaining db views and their pros and cons. That will give you a starting point. At the very least, the articles should confirm most of the comments made here about views.

Answer (score 2):

Views are a SQL construct that have their place. I prefer stored procs usually but do use views when they are the ideal for the task in hand.

Views, used properly, have no performance overhead.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why noone mentioned this, but one of the **huge** benefits is their ability to restrict access to underlying tables. You can deny direct access to tables, create views as you see fit (restricting columns/rows) and grant privileges as your app/project dictates. There is never enough protection.
And as others said, with no performance degradation whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, but he see's that as a con, not a pro. There is only the 3 of us, the manager, the programmer and the part-timer (me), who happens to be more experienced than either of them. But you are right...Explaining that is going to be very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You never needed to use views. Some people feel views are akin to database triggers, and that a database should be treated as simply a stack of data, not its own specialized data processing system.

Performance impact? There should be done.

Who is right? Either/neither. Its just a different philosophy. I see no reason to abandon views.

Comment: Fair enough. I really have no desire to argue, I just want to make sure are decisions are based on solid evidence, then we won't have it haunt us later afterwards....

Answer (score 1):

I love using Views - particularly for data that crosses more than one database. It provides a way to pull such data into a single data construct and obscure the somewhat verbose query. However, they have to be used judiciously and carefully to avoid *performance bottlenecks*. There's not usually a *gain* in performance.

Still - to exclude them out of hand seems unduly draconian. They have their place. In the end it is probably not a battle worth fighting. To borrow from Kung Fu Panda - "view, don't view..... noodle, don't noodle..."

Comment: You make good valid points. The 2 main reasons for views to me, was ease of getting certain sets of data, and having the sql server manage the joins, rather than coldfusion. I did think there was a performance gain, but how much and is it still true? I just don't know.

Comment: My question would be what is the measurable benefit _gained_ by not using not using any views? No, they are not a cure all. But providing a more simplified interface and centralized access point to certain sets of data is a strong selling point. Especially in databases that support a lot of reports. Views can also provide a layer of insulation against schema changes that is not always possible with cfquery's. (I have not used them much, but ms sql also provides indexed views.) So again one has to ask, what does the application _gain_ by not using them at all? View-phobia is not a good reason.

Comment: ...(cont'd) Re: _it is very inconvenient to have to lookup the code for a view_. Honestly, that is just a normal part of database development. That is like saying do not stored procedures because you have to look up the code. Developer convenience should not be the *sole* deciding factor..

Comment: But the main point he made was that when he had to look at our coldfusion code, he wanted the convenience of having all the sql code there as well, instead of using views, which only show's the needed fields for select, where or order by statements....

Answer (score 0):

> that the performance benefit is
>   minimal

So basically he thought before that there is a significant performance benefit. And noone ever told him to read the manual.

Views NEVER (!) had a performnce benefit. They always have been about easy of use. Like code snippets. MATERIALIZED views are another thing, but they are pretty new and not what was meant here.

Views always were about maing SQL programming easier. They always got evaluated at runtime.

So, basically, you have a notcompetent manager with delusions and not someone cracked them and he overreacts by not seeing the advantages.

Comment: Well when you have a multi-join query as a view, isn't it less work to have the joins done via the view, vs, sending the query with the joins via some web programming language?